# easiest way to parse html from soapui http request

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I created a http request step in soapui which is an html page from which I need to extract one single value from

```
 <span class="result">12345<span>
```

I'm thinking about using groovy,is it the best way ? If yes I'm beginner in both soapui and groovy, any snippet code to get started (how to get html Content from http request step, how to parse in groovy) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel more comfortable with Groovy, then go for it!

SoapUI internally represents *almost* everything as XML. Therefore the easiest way to manipulate things in SoapUI is using XPath. In your case, you could probably use a [Property Transfer](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) step to extract `//span[@class="result"]`.

Comment: I'd prefer your method but seems I have pb "Reference to undefined entity : raquo"

Comment: What is a "pb"? Where is this?

Comment: I mean problem :) nevertheless if it's not possible I found a solution in groovy

Comment: @Siking I think that "pb" means "problem".

Comment: @user310291 so finallly you found a solution using groovy?

Comment: @albciff a dirty one (using index of) but it does the job at least.

Answer (score 0):

Siking answer worked setting the source 'property' to ResponseAsXml along with XPath expresions, as for common HTML XPath expressions there's a resource online at 
https://devhints.io/xpath